# How to save current login name to SharePoint people and group column using angularjs?

Tags: sharepoint-server, rest, angularjs

**Add.js**

```
$scope.addEntity = function (entity, $event) {

            entity.dateString = $("#dpFrom").val();
            entity.ExpDateString = $("#dpTo").val();
            if (entity && entity.project && entity.equipment && entity.eqptagno && entity.wono && entity.processlicensor && entity.Vendor && entity.dateString && entity.ExpDateString && entity.Discipline && entity.Remarks) {
                if (entity.dateString < entity.ExpDateString) {
                    spService.addNew(entity)
                    .then(function (response) {
                        $location.path("/");
                    });
                    //$event.preventDefault();
                    $scope.FormActionMessage = "ERF Forwarded to Project Manager. Please check Requester Dashboard for the update!";
                    // $window.alert("ERF Forwarded to Project Manager. Please check Requester Dashboard for the update!");
                    // clearForm();
                    $scope.IsVisible = false;
                    event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false;

                } else {
                    //$window.alert("ERF Not Submitted!... Expected Date of Demobilisation should be greater than Date of Requirement!");
                    $scope.FormActionMessage("ERF Not Submitted!... Expected Date of Demobilisation should be greater than Date of Requirement!");
                    event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false;
                }
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        };
```

**Entity.js**

```
var addNew = function (entity) {
        var data = {
            __metadata: { 'type': 'SP.Data.ERFListItem' },
            Project: entity.project,
            Equipment_Category: entity.equipment,
            Equipment_Tag_Number: entity.eqptagno,
            PO_Number_For_Vendor_Expat: entity.wono,
            Licensor_Name: entity.processlicensor,
            Vendor: entity.Vendor,
            Date_Of_Requirement: entity.dateString,
            Expected_Date_Of_Demobilisation: entity.ExpDateString,
            Discipline: entity.Discipline,
            Remarks: entity.Remarks,
            Sub_Flag: "F",
            Action_Flag: "FM",
            ERF_Status: "Requester Forwarded ERF To PM",
            ERF_Created_By: entity.currentUser
        };
        var url = listEndPoint + "/GetByTitle('ERF')/Items";
        return baseService.postRequest(data, url);
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

SharePoint people or group column requires user's or group's `Id` to save into it.

You can get current user's Id from `_spPageContextInfo`

```
var userId = _spPageContextInfo.userId;
```

Now let's say your people or group column name is `Vendor`. So in the request body it should look like:

```
var data = {
   VendorId: userId
};
```

More details is [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/990131/CRUD-Operation-to-List-Using-SharePoint-Rest-API).